# Does ELBO contain the reconstruction loss info in variational autoencoders

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, autoencoder

This is a related question to this -  [Variational autoencoder and reconstruction Log Probability vs Reconstruction error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070393/variational-autoencoder-and-reconstruction-log-probability-vs-reconstruction-err)

I'm trying to understand how variational autoencoders are optimized. I've read the math behind it and I think I understand the general concept of variational inference and the reparameterization trick used for the latent space.

I've seen some [examples](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-variational-autoencoders-1bfe67eb5daf) where the input and the output are compared to each other using cross entropy and KL divergence is on the latent variables. And then this loss is minimized.

On the other hand, there are [other examples](https://jaan.io/what-is-variational-autoencoder-vae-tutorial/) which uses the log probabilities and the KL divergence to generate the evidence lower bound (ELBO). Then the negative of the ELBO value is minimized.

In both, the latent space is partitioned based on the patterns of the inputs (numbers in MNIST for example). So I wonder if the ELBO is or contains information similar to the reconstruction loss.

Comment: The first link you posted is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is Yes. The ELBO is actually a smooth objective function which is a lower bound of the log likelihood.

Instead of maximize log p(x) where x is an observed image, we opt for maximing log p(xlz) + KL(q(zlx) ll p(z)) where z is sample from the encoder q(zlx). We do this because it is easier to optimize the ELBO than log p(x).

Then the term p(xlz) is a negative reconstruct error - we want to maximize the likihood of x given a latent variable z.
For the first example: p(xlz) is a gaussian distribution with a variance of 1.

The second example: p(xlz) is a Bernoulli distribution since Mnist digit is a black and white. We can model each pixel as how much brightness it is.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that optimizing by ELBO does not necessarily push the autoencoder to create accurate reconstructions but rather create reconstructions that are likely to occur in the given dataset

Comment: Simply, we should not expect low reconstruction loss (high accuracy) in variational autoencoders because that is not the absolute objective?

Comment: Yes, that is a good intuition. It will not accurately reconstruct the input image. It actually learns a conditional probability distribution p(xlz) via the decoder function. This is important for a generative model because we want to generalize the dataset, but not overfit to some subset of the data.

Comment: For the low reconstruct loss, I think we don't want the model to learn the encoder and decoder that generate too low reconstruction error because it is kinda overfitting. Interestingly, a low reconstruction loss is related to a sharper image. In that sense, an adversarial training  that generates a sharper image actually avoids dealing with the reconstruction term. And it produces a higher quality image than VAE.